# Joining table get the first data on first table if duplicate

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hi i have `table1` and `table2`.
  `table1` is the logtime table of employees and `table2` is the groupcode of the employee.
 On `table1` some employees has duplicate time in because they time in multiple time to just to secure their time in.

Table1

```
ID  EMPID       Time_IN
1   001     7:01 AM
2   004     7:04 AM
3   034     7:10 AM
4   034     7:11 AM
5   019     7:11 AM
6   019     7:12 AM
```

Table2

```
ID  empID   GroupName
1   001     AA
2   004     AB
3   034     AA
4   019     AA
```

result

```
GroupName   CNT
AA          5
AB          1
```

Expected result

```
GroupName   CNT
AA          3
AB          1
```

current query

```
Select b.GroupName, count(*) as cnt
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on a.EMPID = b.empID    
Group by  b.GroupName
```

How can i achive as expected result above?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `distinct count` as follows:

```
select t2.groupname, count(distinct empid) as cnt
from table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.empid = t2.empid
group by t2.groupname
```

Answer (score 1):

The `join` is superfluous for the question you have asked:

```
select t2.GroupName, count(*) as cnt
from table2 t2
group by t2.GroupName;
```

This is much more efficient than `join`ing and using `count(distinct)`.  You probably really have a different question, which should be asked as a *new* question.